# Regex - check if no white space before and after a name

Tags: regex, whitespace

With this regex

```
[A-Z]{1}[a-z]+(?<! )|[A-Z]{1}[a-z]+(?![a-z]* )
```

I want to match the following items.

```
# match them
AaaaBbbbCcccccDddddd

# don't match them
Aaaaa Bbbbbb
Ccccc Eeeee
```

In my regex I use an OR operator. But this is still wrong. Until now all items are matched. I need an AND operator but didn't found it.

Comment: So you want four matches `Aaaa`, `Bbbb`, `Cccccc`, and `Dddddd`? All from the first line? And you don't want to match the other Words as they are surrounded by spaces on one of their sides?

Comment: Maybe `(?<![ A-Z])[A-Z][a-z]+(?![a-z ])`? See https://regex101.com/r/PUyP1I/1

Comment: Maybe `(?<=[a-z]|^)([A-Z][a-z]+)(?=[A-Z]|$)`? See https://regex101.com/r/8YvAnC/1

Comment: Hello, both answers are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
(?<![ A-Z])[A-Z][a-z]+(?![a-z ])
(?<![\sA-Z])[A-Z][a-z]+(?![a-z\s])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PUyP1I/1).

*Details*:

- `(?<![\sA-Z])` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is a whitespace or an uppercase letter immediately to the left of the current location
- `[A-Z]` - an uppercase letter
- `[a-z]+` - one or more lowercase letters
- `(?![a-z\s])` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a whitespace or a lowercase letter immediately to the right of the current location.